# Input n number of strings in Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Initially I am trying to take an integer t as input then t lines follow  each containing a string.I am getting runtime error in the code in Python 3.4.1 i.e 'File "./prog.py", line 1, in 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line'.Can you please point out where have I gone wrong?

```
for i in range(input()): 
    d = input()
    a = list(d)
    b = set(a)
    print (len(b))
```

Comment: For a start, your code is all on one line.

Comment: its not in one line OP didn't formated it i think

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: Unrelated to your error (which Bhat pointed out below): You don't need the intermediate step of converting to a list - you can call `set(d)` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only error is that you need to convert `range(input())` to `range(int(input()))` because simple `input()` is a string and has no range:

```
>>> for i in range(int(input())):
...      d=input()
...      a=list(d)
...      b=set(a)
...      print(len(b))
... 
4
Hello
4
There
4
are
3
selective
7
```